# What does it mean that random effects are highly correlated?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

What does it mean when two random effects are highly or perfectly correlated?
That is, in R when you call summary on a mixed model object, under "Random effects" "corr" is 1 or -1.

```
summary(model.lmer) 
Random effects:
Groups   Name                    Variance   Std.Dev.  Corr                 
popu     (Intercept)             2.5714e-01 0.5070912                      
          amdclipped              4.2505e-04 0.0206167  1.000               
          nutrientHigh            7.5078e-02 0.2740042  1.000  1.000        
          amdclipped:nutrientHigh 6.5322e-06 0.0025558 -1.000 -1.000 -1.000
```

I know this is bad and indicates that the random effects part of the model is too complex, but I'm trying to understand

- 1)what is doing on statistically
- 2)what is going on practically with
  the structure of the response variables.

**Example**

Here is an example based on "[GLMMs in action: gene-by-environment interaction in total fruit production of wild populations of Arabidopsis thaliana](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAC&url=http://glmm.wdfiles.com/local--files/examples/Banta_ex.pdf&ei=hTNYUpuzBu7J4APN5YHYBg&usg=AFQjCNG65VjvqOLeYLFxJZnzmlMevgEbuA&bvm=bv.53899372,d.dmg)"
by Bolker et al

Download data

```
download.file(url = "http://glmm.wdfiles.com/local--files/trondheim/Banta_TotalFruits.csv", destfile = "Banta_TotalFruits.csv")
dat.tf <- read.csv("Banta_TotalFruits.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Set up factors

```
dat.tf <- transform(dat.tf,X=factor(X),gen=factor(gen),rack=factor(rack),amd=factor(amd,levels=c("unclipped","clipped")),nutrient=factor(nutrient,label=c("Low","High")))
```

Modeling log(total.fruits+1) with "population" (popu) as random effect

```
model.lmer <- lmer(log(total.fruits+1) ~ nutrient*amd + (amd*nutrient|popu), data= dat.tf)
```

Accessing the Correlation matrix of the random effects show that everything is perfectly correlated

```
attr(VarCorr(model.lmer)$popu,"correlation")

                         (Intercept) amdclipped nutrientHigh amdclipped:nutrientHigh
(Intercept)                       1          1            1                      -1
amdclipped                        1          1            1                      -1
nutrientHigh                      1          1            1                      -1
amdclipped:nutrientHigh          -1         -1           -1                       1
```

I understand that these are the correlation coefficients of two vectors of random effects coefficients, such as

```
cor(ranef(model.lmer)$popu$amdclipped, ranef(model.lmer)$popu$nutrientHigh)
```

Does a high correlation mean that the two random effects contain redundant information?  Is this analogous to multicollinearity in multiple regression when a model with highly correlated predictors should be simplified?

Comment: One thing I noticed that the variances in your original example are very small 6.5e-6 = 0.00000065. It depends a bit on how you scaled your variables, but to me this suggest that either you need to rethink the scale of your variables or your variance is _de facto_ zero

Comment: I don't seem to be able to replicate your results. Which version of `lme4` are you using? If you are not using version 1.0-4 or newer I would recommend upgrading before anything else. Currently I get `a  failure to converge in 10000 evaluations` message.

Comment: Can you include the entire model summary or provide a link to it?

Answer (score 5):

I am not a 100% sure this answer is correct but given that I just found to have the same issue (perfect correlation) and looking at my own data here is what I assume is happening.

If there is no variation within your grouping (random) variables, the correlation will be either +1 (if both effects have the same sign) or -1.

So e.g. for your example, I would assume that for each value of `amd` there is only 1 value of `nutrient`. This lack of variance creates the perfect correlation.

I do not necessarily think this is problematic, it chiefly depends on your model's objective. Check out [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31569/questions-about-how-random-effects-are-specified-in-lmer) for an excellent explanation of how different random effects are used with `lmer`.

The main point seems to be. If you are using a random slope variable - `y ~ x3 + (1 + x1 | x2)` and you know that for each value of `x2` , `x1` is meant to be constant, the random slope can still be justified, provided you have good (theoretical / empirical) reason to assume that for each `x2` the effect of `x1` on your response variable `y` will be different.

I know it's an old question but hopefully my suggested answer makes some sense.

Simon