# Analytical form of Linear Mixed Model Regression With Interacting Random Effects?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, interaction

I have been reading up on Linear Mixed Models with random slopes, and I have a question that I could not find addressed anywhere. I have seen a lot of R model formulae ([example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31569/questions-about-how-random-effects-are-specified-in-lmer)) where random slopes interact with fixed effects, but what is the analytical form of the regression equation when a mixed model has a random effect that interacts with a fixed effect?

Assume we have a model of experiment data such that `Y ~ X1 + X2 + X1:X2 + (1+X1|participants)`, where there is a random slope for `X1` as well as a random intercept to allow for individual difference between participants.

From [this link](https://stattrek.com/multiple-regression/interaction), it is clear that the regression model for fixed interaction effects would have the following equation:

$$
\hat{Y} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}X_{1} + \beta_{2}X_{2} + \beta_{3}X_{1}X_{2} + \epsilon
$$

And from [this link](https://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/learning/videos/random-slopes.html), it is clear that the mixed model without the interaction effects, would have the following equation:

$$
\hat{Y} = (\beta_{0} + u_{0}) + (\beta_{1} + u_{1})X_{1} + \beta_{2}X_{2} + \epsilon
$$

where $u_{0}$ and $u_{1}$ are the jointly normally distributed random variations.

How are these two equations combined in the aforementioned case, where `X1` is a random effect and there is an interaction between that and the fixed effect `X2`? Would $\beta_{3}$ change as a result, such that $\beta_{3}$ also varies between participants? Is the following equation right, or is something missing?

$$
\hat{Y} = (\beta_{0} + u_{0}) + (\beta_{1} + u_{1})X_{1} + \beta_{2}X_{2} + \beta_{3}X_{1}X_{2} + \epsilon
$$

The concrete example is that I'm trying to model data of temporal increase in measure `Y` over the course of the experiment, where `X1` is the time variable and `X2` is the categorical condition variable (0 or 1). I need the interaction variable because I am trying to test the significance of the difference in temporal increase in Y between the two conditions, and I want to allow for the possibility that this temporal increase (slope of `X1`) differs between participants. The study is between participants, so for a given participant, `X2` is either always 0 or always 1.

I hope the question makes sense. Thanks in advance! :)